# QGIS 3.4 set transparency only for some layers below

Tags: qgis-3, mapping, transparency-opacity

I‘m working on a geomorphological map of a river and its sourroundings. As a base I have a topographic map and a DEM for the pre-mapping. The topographic map is not accurate enough in the river gulley, so I covered it with a polygon to give me the possibility to draw on the polygon instead of on the misleading topological map when I‘ll do my field work. But I set the opacity of my polygon to 100% it will also cover my DEM (but I‘d like to see through the DEM but not the topographic map). Is there a way set a layers opacity to different percentages for the different layers below?

Or do you have any other ideas how I can fix this problem, e.g. cutting the topographic map on the riverborders?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:Se @ShangriLa! Have you seen the `Layer Order Panel` if you right-click anywhere on the toolbar. This let's you set which layers are rendered over others. So you can ensure your topographic map is always shown if you place this at the top of the order. Then put the DEM second and add some percentage transparency. And the same for the polygon with a greater transparency. See if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Layer rendering section use layer blending mode  as Multiple or Darken, play to see what will give you best results.